# Example of non-discrete space that admits an infinite open cover formed by pairwise disjoint open spaces

Tags: general-topology

Can someone give me an example of a non-discrete space that admits an infinite open cover formed by pairwise disjoint open spaces?
I'm trying to find some but I can't. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you mean for example $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$? You can write each connected component as an infinite nested union of open sets.

Comment: What do you mean by "two by two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb R - \mathbb Z = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} \, (n-1,n)$.

The space $\mathbb R - \mathbb Z$ is not discrete, each set $(n-1,n)$ is open in $\mathbb R - \mathbb Z$, and if $m \ne n \in \mathbb Z$ then the two sets $(m-1,m)$ and $(n-1,n)$ are disjoint.